# Standard python function to split paths?

Tags: python, path, standard-library

#### NOTE: Please, don't code it for me.  *I already have a home-rolled function* to do what I describe below.

Is there a function ***in the standard Python library*** that will take an absolute path as argument, and return a tuple of all its "atomic" path components, after removing all redundant ones (e.g. `./`), resolving bits like `../`, etc.?  For example, given the Unix path `/s//pam/../ham/./eggs`, the output should be

```
('/', 's', 'ham', 'eggs')
```

and given the Windows path `C:\s\\pam\..\ham\.\eggs`, the output should be

```
('C:', '\\', 's', 'ham', 'eggs')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as close as you get (AFAIR) with the standard lib:

```
   >>> import os
   >>> help(os.path.split)
    Help on function split in odule ntpath:

    split(p)
        Split a pathname.
        Return tuple (head, tail) where tail is everything after the final slash.
        Either part may be empty.
```

this does not solve your usecase, but is trivially to extend so it does. 
For more info, see the comments.

Comment: It does not do what the OP asks. I think there's no such functionality in the standard library.

Comment: yes, it was proposed, but denied. os.path.split is the cloesest, that's why I mentioned it. for reference: http://bugs.python.org/issue11344

Answer (score 0):

There's no single function that will do what you want...primarily because what you're asking doesn't make any sense from a path-manipulation standpoint (because discarding `..` changes the path in a meaningful fashion).

You could do something along the lines of:

```
[x for x in path.split(os.path.sep) if x not in ['.', '..']]
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> path='/s//pam/../ham/./eggs'
>>> [x for x in path.split(os.path.sep) if x not in ['.', '..']]
['', 's', '', 'pam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

And:

```
>>> path=r'C:\s\\pam\..\ham\.\eggs'
>>> [x for x in path.split(os.path.sep) if x not in ['.', '..']]
['C:', 's', '', 'pam', 'ham', 'eggs']
```

(As long as `os.path.sep` is `\`).

It's obviously not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it points the way in the right direction.

Comment: `os.path.normpath` performs precisely the kind of normalization I'm referring to; there's nothing non-sensical about it; e.g. `posixpath.normpath('/s//pam/../ham/./eggs')` returns `'/s/ham/eggs'`, etc.